# Click outside jQuery modal to close

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have seen various methods to solve this problem, but can't find the solution for my situation (I am not so skilled in java / jQuery anyway). I have a php script that generates the following code - which works fine.

My question is how to modify this so that a click outside the box will also close the modal? (I can handle changing the php the drives the code)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
                {
                    jQuery('#modal-messages').css('margin-top', ((jQuery(window).height() - jQuery('#modal-messages').outerHeight())/2) + jQuery(window).scrollTop() + 'px');
                    jQuery('#modal-messages').css('margin-left', ((jQuery(window).width() - jQuery('#modal-messages').outerWidth())/2) + jQuery(window).scrollLeft() + 'px');
                    jQuery('#modal-messages').show();jQuery('#messages-overlay').show();

                    jQuery('#messages-close-button').click(function()
                    {
                        jQuery('#messages-overlay').hide();
                        jQuery('#modal-messages').hide();
                    });

                    jQuery('#messages-overlay').click(function()
                    {
                        jQuery('#messages-overlay').hide();
                        jQuery('#modal-messages').hide();
                    });jQuery('#modal-messages').bind( 'clickoutside', function(event)
                    {
                        jQuery('#messages-overlay').hide();
                        jQuery('#modal-messages').hide();
                    });});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just add another "greyed out" area below the modal

```
<div id="greyedArea"></div>
```

with the css

```
#greyedArea {
 background: black;
 opacity:0.25;
 width: 100%;
}
```

which you can then use to trigger the closing procedure by using

```
$('#greyedArea').on('click', function() {
 $('#messages-overlay').hide();
 $('#modal-messages').hide();
});
```